# How to either dump/write a MINI PCI-e wireless EEPROM, or extract/edit an INSYDE bios image

Tags: firmware, tags

HP doesn't want to allow people to use any wireless card other than their own by creating a device-id whitelist in the bios. I want to use an atheros card which won't make it past post (however, if I hot-plug it in after post, it works fine). So I have two routes to take..

I want to edit the most recent bios update for my laptop and add the new card's device id's to the wireless whitelist. The bios is insyde, and on previous model laptops..  downloading a bios update simply gave you the FD file which you could edit in EZH2O. However, the new bioses are giving a .bin file that I'm unsure of how to extract the fd file from. Any thoughts from the hivemind?

Failing that, I could try dumping the eeprom of the HP card, and then write an appropriate code to the new card to allow it to bypass the bios check. I know there will be further issues as far as drivers go.. but I just need help with this part. So far, I've been unable to get the linux ethtool to work for me. Any other ideas?

much thanks

Comment: Good luck with that. I would edit that directly from BIOS EEPROM (or alternatively card ID) using for example Bus Pirate (http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Pirate).

Comment: Also, why you have to update your BIOS?

Comment: Maybe some insight here...http://www.mattday.net/content/notes-hacking-insyde-bioss

Comment: @Olli - I need to edit it for a few reasons, but the top 2 are: 1) To bypass HP's totalitarian wireless policy of not allowing non-hp cards. 2) to regain access to the bios menu.. they've intentionally crippled it to provide no options, however if you can change a certain bit, you will get the menu back

Comment: @Moab & Olli - thanks for the links, I'll check 'em out

Answer (score 1):

You will need to find out what the stack flag is so assume:

`peek 0cX000101010001` then `print 0cX000101010001` will give you the output byte segment of the micro controller array thereby allowing you to inject your code in.

The flag `0cX000101010001` was just used as an example to get you started. Remember that you need to know what commands the microcontroller will accept and what it will verbose.